# How to Allow a Multi-function Device or Application to Send E-mail through Office 365 Using SMTP

Tags: office365

I'm new here and I've heard that you guys are the people to go to when all else fails.

I am currently using a HP CM3530fs MFP printer and a problem that I am currently encountering is that I am unable to scan and send emails via an Office365 account to internal email addresses. It was working perfectly up until today when seemingly for no reason it has failed. There are no error messages on the machine, it appears to successfully scan the document but I never receive an email.

I have checked my junk and spam folders, as well as attempted other internal email addresses and I can confirm that I am not receiving the emails.

I have attempted the following combinations and configurations but to no avail

SMTP Gateway:           mail.global.frontbridge.com
Port:                   25

SMTP Gateway:           mail.global.frontbridge.com
Port:                   587

SMTP Gateway:           smtp.office365.com
Port:                   25

SMTP Gateway:           smtp.office365.com
Port:                   587

I have updated the firmware and restarted the machine several times but I am still unable to receive emails from scanned documents.

Would any of you be able to suggest where I might be going wrong?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Gmail and Office365 has upgraded their TLS version from 1 to 2. Your machine may not be supported by TLS version 2. Only TLS version 1.